# Bind on Windows Server 2k8; rndc reload fails for no obvious reason

Tags: windows-server-2008, bind, rndc

I'm trying to install Bind 9.9 on Windows Server 2008, but calling "rndc reload" fails with a very strange error message:

```
PS C:\bind\etc> ..\bin\rndc.exe reload
rndc: error: C:\bind\etc\rndc.conf:1: unknown option ' ■#...'
rndc: error: C:\bind\etc\rndc.conf:5: unknown option ''
rndc: error: C:\bind\etc\rndc.conf:11: unknown option ''
rndc: error: C:\bind\etc\rndc.conf:13: unexpected token near end of file
rndc: could not load rndc configuration
```

Here's the contents of rndc.conf.  I opened the file up in Notepad++ and verified that there are no non-printing characters and the line endings look fine (normal Windows line endings):

```
# Start of rndc.conf
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "vP+yTbzcnlq90UFC4GuNCg==";
};

options {
    default-key "rndc-key";
    default-server 127.0.0.1;
    default-port 953;
};
# End of rndc.conf
```

Here's the contents of named.conf:

```
# Use with the following in named.conf, adjusting the allow list as needed:
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "vP+yTbzcnlq90UFC4GuNCg==";
};

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
# End of named.conf
```

For what it's worth, I have gotten Bind and rndc to work properly on Windows 7 following the same installation process.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Try using a different editor like gvim, notepad doesn't always accurately display the hidden characters.

Comment: `I'm trying to install Bind 9.9 on Windows Server 2008`  There's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you got a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your configuration file. Use a different editor (or [editor setting in Notepad++](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#new-document)) which doesn't add the BOM (and with which you can strip this one out).

Comment: It was in fact the encoding issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check your character encoding; make sure it's at least set to ANSI.